# SQL Incorrect syntax when trying to CREATE PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting an error while trying to execute in SQL Server:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sql_chp4a_premiere_assign, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

I assume it refers to the first `SELECT`. I'm not very familiar with SQL just yet (as well as not having had class in awhile due to horrible storms and Spring Break) so it's probably something stupid I've overlooked.

```
USE [school username that gives out my name)

CREATE PROCEDURE sql_chp4a_premiere_assign

SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,PRICE 
FROM PART;

SELECT *
FROM ORDERS

SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME 
FROM customer 
WHERE CREDIT_LIMIT>=10000;

SELECT ORDER_NUM
FROM ORDERS
WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM = '608'
AND ORDER_DATE = '2010-10-23';

SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM,CUSTOMER_NAME 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE REP_NUM=35 OR REP_NUM=65;

SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION 
FROM PART WHERE CLASS!='AP';

SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,ON_HAND 
FROM PART 
WHERE ON_HAND BETWEEN 10 AND 25;

SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,ON_HAND 
FROM PART 
WHERE ON_HAND>=10 AND ON_HAND<=25;

SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,(ON_HAND * PRICE) 
AS "ON_HAND_VALUE" 
FROM PART WHERE CLASS='SG';

SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,(ON_HAND * PRICE) 
AS "ON_HAND_VALUE" 
FROM PART 
WHERE (ON_HAND * PRICE)>7500;

SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,(ON_HAND * PRICE) 
AS "ON_HAND_VALUE" 
FROM PART WHERE (ON_HAND * PRICE)>7500;
```

Thanks, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: The error is because you're missing the `AS` - [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx).  Secondly, the sproc is selecting a lot but doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

You're wrong in this part:

```
USE [school username that gives out my name)
```

Change `)` to `]`:

```
USE [school username that gives out my name]
```

Second:

You're missing `AS`, `BEGIN` and `END` keyword in stored procedure declaration.

Third:

You're created two stored procedures. Separate each stored procedure declaration with `GO`

This will work:

```
USE [school username that gives out my name]

go

CREATE PROCEDURE Sql_chp4a_premiere_assign
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             price
      FROM   part;

      SELECT *
      FROM   orders

      SELECT customer_name
      FROM   customer
      WHERE  credit_limit >= 10000;

      SELECT order_num
      FROM   orders
      WHERE  customer_num = '608'
             AND order_date = '2010-10-23';

      SELECT customer_num,
             customer_name
      FROM   customer
      WHERE  rep_num = 35
              OR rep_num = 65;

      SELECT part_num,
             description
      FROM   part
      WHERE  class != 'AP';

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             on_hand
      FROM   part
      WHERE  on_hand BETWEEN 10 AND 25;

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             on_hand
      FROM   part
      WHERE  on_hand >= 10
             AND on_hand <= 25;

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             ( on_hand * price ) AS "ON_HAND_VALUE"
      FROM   part
      WHERE  class = 'SG';

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             ( on_hand * price ) AS "ON_HAND_VALUE"
      FROM   part
      WHERE  ( on_hand * price ) > 7500;

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             ( on_hand * price ) AS "ON_HAND_VALUE"
      FROM   part
      WHERE  ( on_hand * price ) > 7500;
  END;

go

CREATE PROCEDURE Sql_chp4a_premiere_assign
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             price
      FROM   part;

      SELECT *
      FROM   orders

      SELECT customer_name
      FROM   customer
      WHERE  credit_limit >= 10000;

      SELECT order_num
      FROM   orders
      WHERE  customer_num = '608'
             AND order_date = '2010-10-23';

      SELECT customer_num,
             customer_name
      FROM   customer
      WHERE  rep_num = 35
              OR rep_num = 65;

      SELECT part_num,
             description
      FROM   part
      WHERE  class != 'AP';

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             on_hand
      FROM   part
      WHERE  on_hand BETWEEN 10 AND 25;

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             on_hand
      FROM   part
      WHERE  on_hand >= 10
             AND on_hand <= 25;

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             ( on_hand * price ) AS "ON_HAND_VALUE"
      FROM   part
      WHERE  class = 'SG';

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             ( on_hand * price ) AS "ON_HAND_VALUE"
      FROM   part
      WHERE  ( on_hand * price ) > 7500;

      SELECT part_num,
             description,
             ( on_hand * price ) AS "ON_HAND_VALUE"
      FROM   part
      WHERE  ( on_hand * price ) > 7500;
  END
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) for Stored Procedures syntax.

Anyway, you can use [this](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) to format your SQL.

Comment: That gives me ""Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sql_chp4a_premiere_assign, Line 8 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.""

Comment: @user2109696: separate `USE` with `CREATE STORED PROCEDURE` using `GO`.. I've edited my answer

Comment: `AS` is required. `BEGIN` and `END` aren't (although they are often used)

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sql_chp4a_premiere_assign
```

to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sql_chp4a_premiere_assign AS
```

Comment: Michael, that changed the error to "Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sql_chp4a_premiere_assign, Line 8
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch."

Comment: @user, put a GO after the USE statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sql_chp4a_premiere_assign
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,PRICE 
    FROM PART;

    SELECT *
    FROM ORDERS

    SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE CREDIT_LIMIT>=10000;

    SELECT ORDER_NUM
    FROM ORDERS
    WHERE CUSTOMER_NUM = '608'
    AND ORDER_DATE = '2010-10-23';

    SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM,CUSTOMER_NAME 
    FROM CUSTOMER 
    WHERE REP_NUM=35 OR REP_NUM=65;

    SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION 
    FROM PART WHERE CLASS!='AP';

    SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,ON_HAND 
    FROM PART 
    WHERE ON_HAND BETWEEN 10 AND 25;

    SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,ON_HAND 
    FROM PART 
    WHERE ON_HAND>=10 AND ON_HAND<=25;

    SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,(ON_HAND * PRICE) 
    AS "ON_HAND_VALUE" 
    FROM PART WHERE CLASS='SG';

    SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,(ON_HAND * PRICE) 
    AS "ON_HAND_VALUE" 
    FROM PART 
    WHERE (ON_HAND * PRICE)>7500;

    SELECT PART_NUM,DESCRIPTION,(ON_HAND * PRICE) 
    AS "ON_HAND_VALUE" 
    FROM PART WHERE (ON_HAND * PRICE)>7500;
END
```